# How do you fill up a directed depth first search with the time which came and time at which it left?

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

How do you fill up a directed depth first search with the time which came and time at which it left? Does it matter whether its direct or undirected for DFS?

for example

[image]

Comment: "Does it matter whether its direct or undirected for DFS?" - Yes. - "How do you fill up a directed depth first search with the time which came and time at which it left?" - No idea what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking, "How do you fill up a directed depth first search with the VISITING time[first of course] and FINISHING time?"

Comment: yes thats exactly what I'm talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply keep a counter and assign-and-increase it each time you start and finish the DFS on a node. As the node to choose for starting the DFS of your picture (as it visits all the nodes in the graph and not just the ones connected to the `U` node), you would have to create a fake node that is connected to all the nodes in the graph and call the DFS on that node.

```java
int time = 0;
HashSet<Vertex> visited = new HashSet<>();

DFS(Vertex v){
    v.start = time++;
    v.end = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(Vertex t : v.neighbors){
        if(!visited.contains(t)){
            visited.add(t);
            DFS(t)
        }
        else if(t.start < v.start && t.end < v.start)
            //cross edge
        else if(t.start < v.start)
            //back edge
        else if(t.start > v.start)
            //forward edge

    }
    v.end = time++;
}
```